# Multiple broadcasts calling themselves with AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am building a water-reminder application in Android and I want to remind the user to drink water multiples times during the day without the user having to open the app (so that the intent to the broadcast receiver will be sent). What's the best way to do that? Here's my code:

AlertReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotification(context, "DRINK", "Time to hydrate", "Alert");
    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {

        PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_announcement)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText(msgText)
                .setTicker(msgAlert);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);

        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Part of MainActivity.java

```
Long alertTime = nextAlarm.getTimeInMillis();
        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can schedule the next drink alarm in your `AlertReceiver` when you display the notification. Should be able to do it the same way that your do it in your Activity. I would also recommend creating another receiver that looks for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast since all alarms are deleted when a device is powered off.

Comment: So you mean I should do the whole process of figuring out when the next alarm should be inside the `AlertReceiver` ?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. That way, any time an alarm is displayed, it will automatically schedule the next one as well. NOTE: the user would still need to open the app once so that the initial alarm can be registered. But after that, your broadcast receiver can handle scheduling and display of alarms.

Comment: Either open it or have it broadcasted when it boots, right?

Comment: You could have your Activity check if there is currently an alarm scheduled or not (this would schedule your app on first open), and you would also want a separate Broadcast Receiver that listens for BOOT_COMPLETED (device restart/boot), that would register your next alarm since all alarms are deleted on device restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORRECTION YOU WON'T NEED THE BACKGROUND SERVICE.
You'll need to put it in a background service.

According to the information in the posted tutorial. You may not have your alarm service wired up quite right.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks

In Activity

```
Long alertTime = nextAlarm.getTimeInMillis();
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

//ADD THIS
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);

    // REMOVE THIS: 
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

This should accomplish what you need to do based on the information you've provided and the details in that tutorial

Comment: I didn't understand how this works, can you give an example on how I would do this in this case? (Hope you understood what I want to do).

Comment: Sorry for the many comments, but I still don't get how I will stop the alarm for the day and start it again the next day without the user having to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ya this is right way to do it. If you want call Scheduling Repeating Alarms please check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/scheduling/alarms.html) link.

Comment: I have already read that, but it doesn't explain how, at the end of the day, I am going to stop the alarm and start it again the next day at a specific time. This should happen without the user having to open the app.

Comment: For that you can check current time when you received broadcast.